# jQuery .has(":focus") in FF/Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a textbox that has filter as you type results below it. I have jQuery that detects when focus leaves the textbox so it can hide the results div.  BUT I don't want to hide the results if the results are click on so that I can use that click to redirect to a different page for that item.

I'm using `.has(":focus")` to check if my results div **or any of its children** have focus. My problem is that this only works in IE as far as I can tell.  Anyone know why?

```
$("#TextBox").blur(function () {
    if ($("#ResultsDIV").has(":focus").length == 0) {  //if you click on anything other than the results
        $("#ResultsDIV").hide();  //hide the results
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Climbage I've got this working...

```
var resultsSelected = false;
$("#ResultsDIV").hover(
    function () { resultsSelected = true; },
    function () { resultsSelected = false; }
);
$("#TextBox").blur(function () {
    if (!resultsSelected) {  //if you click on anything other than the results
        $("#ResultsDIV").hide();  //hide the results
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cB2CN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all not elements on the DOM actually accept focus, and it's up to the browser to decide which ones do.  See [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Maybe have a `hover` event on your `#ResultsDIV` that sets a global variable to determine if the element has focus when you click on it.